# wp_enqueue_style places css in footer instead of the header

Tags: css, wordpress, action, footer

I have the following pieces of code that I use to include styles and java-scripts on a settings page within the WordPress admin area. I have a class with a singleton that I use to initiate my admin pages. I stripped everything except the needed pieces of code to make it more readable.

The problem that I'm having is that by using the set-up below is that the style-sheets on the settings page are placed at the bottom of the page instead of in the head of the page. I can get it in the header by using other action hooks, but that would defeat the purpose. As far as I know the set-up I used is the same setup as is described with the wp_enqueue_style command.

There is a small hint with the command "wp_enqueue_style() can now be called mid-page (in the HTML body). This will load styles in the footer.". If that is true that would mean that the 'admin_print_scripts-*' hook is called somewhere mid-page instead of at the start en doing so places the css in the footer.

Any thoughts on that. an I doing something wrong ?

Thanks for your time.

This is how the singleton class is called within the functions.php file

```
theme::instance( );
```

This is part of the class that I used to create the admin pages

```
class theme {
  static public function instance( )
  {
    is_null( self::$instance ) AND self::$instance = new self;

    return self::$instance;
  }

  public function __construct()
  {
    add_action( 'admin_menu', array( $this, 'initMenu' ), 10, 0 );
    add_action( 'admin_init', array( $this, 'registerAssets' ), 10, 0 );
  }

  public function registerAssets( )
  {
    // Styles
    wp_register_style( 'cen', 'style.css', array( ), '1.0' );
    wp_register_style( 'cen-settings', 'settings.css', array( 'cen' ), '1.0' );

    // Scripts
    wp_register_script( 'cen', 'settings.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0', true );
  }

  public function initMenu( )
  {
    // Index page
    $index =add_menu_page( 'Cen', 'Cen', 'manage_options', 'cen-index', function (){ require_once( get_template_directory( ) . '/pages/index.php' ); }, get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/icons/logo_16.png', "110.00" );

    // Settings page
    $settings =add_submenu_page( 'cen-index', 'Cen - Settings', 'cen' ), 'Settings', 'manage_options', 'cen-settings', function (){ require_once( get_template_directory( ) . '/pages/settings.php' ); } );

    // Add action for assets on the settings page
    add_action( 'admin_print_scripts-' . $settings, array( $this, 'initSettingsPage' ));
  }

  public function initSettingsPage( )
  {
    // Styles used
    wp_enqueue_style( 'cen' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'cen-settings' );

    // Scripts used
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-tabs' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'cen' );
  }
}
```

Comment: why is it a problem that they are at the bottom? those milliseconds they are not in effect should pose no problem?

Comment: I would like to have nice and clean code. I've always learned that the stylesheet should be placed in the head of the page. Also Yslow complains when the stylesheet is not in the header and will deducts points for that. So, basically that is the main reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The action hook `admin_print_scripts` you're using is used to add inline script so it's strongly recommended to use `admin_enqueue_scripts` to enqueue scripts/styles in the admin.
Try it. Hope it works!

Comment: By using admin_enqueue_scripts it does work as I want it to. Within the initMenu I changed the hook to 'admin_enqueue_scripts' and I changed the initSettingsPage function into initAssets and added an if construction to check if I'm on the right page. The if makes it a bit uglier, but it works like I intended it to. Thanks